# Cancel delete vote

Tags: support, deleted-questions, down-votes, deletions

For closing votes, before a question is closed (5 votes) I can cancel my closing vote (after which I can't vote anymore).

After a deletion vote (of a closed question with score $\le -3$), I tried to cancel my deletion vote (the question is not yet deleted) but it doesn't seem to be doable. Is this a bug or is it on purpose (I see no serious reason)? or is there some way to cancel my deletion vote I would have missed?

Comment: A feature request on Meta Stack Exchange: [Ability to retract reopen/delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061). (Since it is not tagged ([status-complete](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/status-complete)), I suppose there is now not a way to cancel a vote to delete. I get the same from the post on Mathematics Meta: [Is it possible to withdraw a deletion vote?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20822))

Comment: @MartinSleziak I'll accept this if you make it an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, at the moment it is not possible to retract a delete vote:

- The feature request [Ability to retract reopen/delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061) on Meta Stack Exchange is not marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).
- Other questions on Meta Stack Exchange about this problem seem to be often closed as duplicate of this post. Among the [linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/193061) I can see this question from January 2017: [Why can't I undo a delete vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289699)
- The answer to [Is it possible to withdraw a deletion vote?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20822) on Mathematics Meta says the same thing. (It is a post from 2015, but I have not seen some update about this on that meta site since then.)

Comment: I have expanded my comments slightly and posted as an answer - per [request by the OP](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4079/cancel-delete-vote/4081#comment18179_4079).

Comment: Thanks for the correction @HughThomas (I should have noticed the typo - especially since in changed the meaning.)

Comment: In my experience, people have used delete votes to harass and unjustly censor certain areas of mathematics.